# Android browser doesn't work with geolocation

Tags: java, php, android, browser, geolocation

I am building a website which use geolocation code, It suppose to load mapCanvas and after user click on "Finde Me!" button get his location and set a center of a map based on user location. It's working fine with Firefox, Chrome, Safari, tested on regular PC and iPhone the only device doesn't work with it is any mobile phone with Android. here is a code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&key=YourKey" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var iconBlue = new GIcon(); 
    iconBlue.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
    iconBlue.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(17, 25);
    iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(1, 1);
    iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);

    var iconRed = new GIcon(); 
    iconRed.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
    iconRed.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconRed.iconSize = new GSize(17, 25);
    iconRed.shadowSize = new GSize(1, 1);
    iconRed.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconRed.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);

    var customIcons = [];
    customIcons["restaurant"] = iconBlue;
    customIcons["bar"] = iconRed;

    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(50.061795,19.936924), 16);

        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
        GDownloadUrl("Your_xml.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
    //]]>


function findLoc(){
if (!navigator.geolocation) {
alert('Sorry, your browser does not support Geo Services');
}
else {
// Get the current location    
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMap);
}
}
function showMap(position){
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;
var myPoint = new GLatLng(lat, lon);
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
map.setCenter(myPoint, 15);
GDownloadUrl("Your_xml.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
            map.addOverlay(marker);

}
       });

function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any solution to make it work.
PS
There is no errors or statements giving any hint making it more understandable. 
Device got GPS enable. 
pleas help I've been trying to figure it out for 2 weeks

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you just have an arduous old-fashioned debug in front of you.  My approach would be to add visible output at various important points in the code (just before and after `getCurrentPosition` is called, and at the beginning of `showMap`, for instance) and narrow down from there just where the failure is occurring.  Once you know what's failing you can probably develop an idea of why, but until you know that you're flailing in the dark.

(I've worked on a geolocation-based mobile webapp that supported Android, so in case you need any reassurance, there's nothing inherently impossible about your situation.)

Comment: thx for answer I've added an alert('Success!') just before navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMap); and its show me my Success! that means this function findLoc was triggered something is wrong with showMap funtion but I don't know what

Comment: @TomLiland: Right.  Now you keep going with that until you find out what part of the code is actually failing.  First, an alert at the beginning of `showMap` tells you whether that function is actually getting called.  And so on; the general principle should be clear by now.

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMap) this wasn't called after function findLock started. I placed an alert right after navigator and message didn't show up. On iPhone I got all the message. Strange tiny thing :(